# How to add a friend from a different Diaspora pod?

Tags: diaspora

I have a profile at the Diaspora pod called [pod.geraspora.de](http://pod.geraspora.de)

My real-life friend has a profile at the Diaspora pod called [joindiaspora.com](http://joindiaspora.com)

**QUESTION:** How can I add this friend?

My id: https://pod.geraspora.de/u/nicolasraoul
My friend's id: https://joindiaspora.com/u/nameofmyfriend

Searching by name or id does not work.
We have both connected Diaspora to Facebook, but it says "not on Diaspora".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on different servers, you need to use your full Diaspora IDs. Type something like `nameofyourfriend@joindiaspora.com` into the search field at the top, and it should find his account after a while. (Or he can do the same with your full ID.)

Another option (if you cannot find him for some reason): On the right side there is a link titled *Share this link via email, blog, or favorite social network!*. Just send him this link and he should be able to connect to you by visiting it.